# Error appears in Accpac integration

Tags: runtime-error, sage-erp, accpac

I'm trying to do an integration between sage  7.0 and  5.5 and when i try to open a session i get an error

> ```
> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
> (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
> ```

I tried every solution online the target machine is set to 86x the dll's are registered the OS is server 2012, any suggestions?

Comment: Need more information.  Is the 5.5 version Sage 300 ERP or a different Sage accounting product line?  Need to see some code, too.